# In RHEL 7.9, the panel at the bottom does not allow to reorder the tabs. Where can I access the panel settings?

Tags: rhel, gnome, desktop-environment

I moved from RHEL 6.9 to 7.9 server variant at my work. I'm no more able to reorder the tabs on the panel at the bottom of the page or resize it. Where can I find the settings to change the panel properties?

Comment: What desktop environment are you using?

Comment: echo $XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP gave me GNOME. Is that what you wanted to know?